# Ruby excetend multiple class inside Module

Tags: ruby, module

Hello someone can help me? I need to extend multiple class inside one module, i try in this way but not work.

```
module A
  def hello_A
    puts "hello from module A"
  end

end

module B
  extend A
  class C
    extend A
    def self.hello_B_C
      puts "Hello from Module B => Class C"
    end
  end

  class D
    def self.hello_B_D
      puts "Hello from Module B => Class D"
    end
  end
end

B::C.hello_B_C  => #Hello from Module B => Class C 
B::C.hello_A    => #Hello from module A
B::D.hello_A    => #undefined method `hello_A' for B::D:Class
```

I whold extend module A in Module B, and use hello_A in all subclass of Module B

Answer (score 0):

`B::D.hello_A` wouldn't work.

when you have this:

```
class B
  extend A
  class D
  end
end
```

The class D does not share *any* functionality with B. `B::D` is nothing but a *namespace*.

If you instead did

```
class B
  extend A
  class D < self
  end
end
```

Now D inherits all the behavior from B.